# How do I create a CSV file from all of these elements?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to get the text from both of these sections and turn it into a CSV list from puppeteer:

item number: (Item 1055688)

price: ( $16.59)

here's what I tried but it doesn't seem to work to find the SKU for example:

```
let elements = await.self.page.$$('div[class="row item-row"]');
for (let element of elements) {
    let sku = await element.$eval(('div[class="body-copy custom-body- 
copy"]'), node => node.innerText.trim());
}
```

Here is the code I am trying to extract the data from:

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
<div class="product_desc_txt">

    <a href=" https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/.product.1055688.html 
" class="body-copy-link">
        Pringles Snack Pack Potato Crisps, Original, 0.67 oz, 60 ct
    </a>
    <div class="body-copy custom-body-copy">
       Item&nbsp;1055688
    </div>

    <div class="margin_tp_10"></div>

    <div class="body-copy hidden visible-md visible-sm visible-xs 
visible-lg">

        <span  data-wishlist-linkfee="false" > $16.59</span>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 body-copy text-right hidden visible-xl ">

<span  data-wishlist-linkfee="false" > $16.59</span>


</div>
```

Here is my code so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra")

const pluginStealth = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth")
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth())

puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 })
await page.goto("https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com")
await page.waitFor(5000);
await page.waitForSelector("#header_sign_in");
await page.click("#header_sign_in");
await page.waitForSelector("#logonId");

await page.type('#logonId', 'username', {delay: 20});
await page.type('#logonPassword_id', 'password', {delay: 20});
await page.type('#deliveryZipCode', 'zipcode', {delay: 20});
await page.click('#sign_in_button');

await page.waitForSelector('body > div.bd-specific > div > div > div > div > div > ul > li.set-zip-code.left-lg.colo-md-5.zipped > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a');
await page.click('body > div.bd-specific > div > div > div > div > div > ul > li.set-zip-code.left-lg.colo-md-5.zipped > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a');
await page.waitForSelector('#tiles-body-attribute > div:nth-child(2) > div.myaccount-lists > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > span > h5 > a');
await page.click('#tiles-body-attribute > div:nth-child(2) > div.myaccount-lists > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > span > h5 > a');
```

I am new to puppeteer so I am not sure if I am doing this right at all, any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the structure of your page is similar to [this one](https://codepen.io/vaviloff/pen/GRKVWwp)

In this case you could use the following code:

```
// Find product descriptions
const csv = await page.$$eval('.product_desc_txt', function(products){

    // Iterate over product descriptions
    let csvLines = products.map(function(product){

        // Inside of each product find product SKU and its price
        let productId = product.querySelector(".custom-body-copy").innerText.trim();
        let productPrice = product.querySelector("span[data-wishlist-linkfee]").innerText.trim();

        // Fomrat them as a csv line
        return `${productId};${productPrice}`
    })

    // Join all lines into one file
    return csvLines.join("\n");

});
```

This code with the linked HTML structure produces this:

> Item 1055688;$16.59
>   Item 1055688;$16.59
>   Item 1055688;$16.59
>   Item 1055688;$16.59

---

A more compact way to rewrite that with arrow functions would be the following *(although I don't think it's very readable)*

```
const csv = await page.$$eval('.product_desc_txt', products => products.map(product => product.querySelector(".custom-body-copy").innerText.trim() + ";" + product.querySelector("span[data-wishlist-linkfee]").innerText.trim()).join("\n"));
```

Comment: is it possible to get these two values to separate into two columns A and B? or do I have to separate myself upon loading in excel? Also, how do send this data to a csv file?

Comment: Aren't they now in separate columns? You talked about creating csv, doesn't this look like one?

Comment: Oh, and can I remove the "item" word from the numbers? There are about 200 SKU's I need to gather so I'm also trying to figure out how to grab all the values. The query selector only seems to find this single value but each item/price has the same format as above.

Comment: Yeah it looks like a csv file but I'm not able to find any newly created CSV's after I run this code. Sorry if these questions seems very basic but I'm new to puppeteer and webscraping in general.

Comment: Of course you can remove the word "item", use .replace() method. If the query finds only one item, show the full html structure (you can just tell the url). To write the data to a file, use node.js "fs" module,  there are lots of tutorials.

Comment: var fs = require('fs');                                                                    
    fs.writeFile('test.txt', '${productId};${productPrice}',

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement your code + csv writer into the code I've updated above. Can you take a look? When I run your code at the end of my code it doesn't seem to get me the SKU/price

Comment: Please understand that questions at Stackoverflow are not meant to produce final working code, they are rather for when you're stuck and cannot move forward at all. You seem to be getting more and more good with this stuff and I would do a disservice to your learning by just providing the correct answer.

Comment: As for my code, it is written for the hypothetical html structure I linked to at the beginning of the answer, your structure is probably a bit different in some way. The important thing is you get the idea.

Comment: Hey Vaviloff, I have been trying since Friday to understand how to write files. I simply cannot figure out how to get the code to work to output a CSV file. What does this function do?  // Join all lines into one file
    return csvLines.join("\n");

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to know you were working on figuring that out! I've answered the other question of yours, hope that was helpful. If that were, please accept both answers as solution, thanks.

Comment: *What does this function do? // Join all lines into one file return csvLines.join("\n");* you see .map creates an array with multiple lines inside and .join glues them all together into one string, adding \n between them. That one string can now be written to a file.